# How to calculate uncertainty in an angle given two vectors with relative uncertainty

Tags: linear-algebra, angle, error-propagation

So I want to calculate the relative uncertainty in an angle given two vectors with a given relative uncertainty. 
For the angle calculation I'm using the following formula. 
$$\cos{\alpha} = \frac{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}}{|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|}$$
where: 
$$    \vec{a} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        x_a\\
        y_a\\
        z_a
    \end{bmatrix} \;
    \text{and, } \;
    \vec{b} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        x_b\\ 
        y_b\\ 
        z_b
    \end{bmatrix}$$

When I represent the vectors with the relative uncertainty I get the following:

$$    \vec{a} = 
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        x_{a} \pm x_{a_{error}}\\
        y_{a} \pm y_{a_{error}}\\
        z_{a} \pm z_{a_{error}}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \;
\vec{b} = 
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        x_{b} \pm x_{b_{error}}\\
        y_{b} \pm y_{b_{error}}\\
        z_{b} \pm z_{b_{error}}
    \end{bmatrix}$$

I tried to calculate the relative error in the enumerator and the denominator, but at the end I just got the same error for the enumerator and denominator and since $cos^{-1}(1) = 0$, I'm guessing I have done some sort of mistake. I guess I'm missing some knowledge on how I'm supposed to do this.

When I did the calculation I calculated the relative error for $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$ and then for $|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|$. For both of them I got that the relative error is

$$x_{a_{error}} + x_{b_{error}} + y_{a_{error}} + y_{b_{error}} + z_{a_{error}} + z_{b_{error}}$$

I'm familiar with the basic rules when calculating with uncertainty, but it is still a new topic for me and I'm a but confused about how I should approach this problem.
I can add the whole calculation as well, but I think I'm missing some basic knowledge. Since the result for me don't make any sence. I though that since I'm working with relative uncertainty I could use the basic rules when multiplying, deviding etc for the relative uncertainty.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: For a general function $f(x)$, the error $\delta f$ can be computed using the derivative of $f$. $$\delta f = ||\nabla f \cdot \delta x||_2$$.

Comment: Since you say you are not sure about the basics, I recommend you to check this from a reliable source.